# what is . in permission list (-rw-rw-r--.)

Tags: linux, permissions

what is . in file or directory permision

e.g. -rw-rw-r--. 1 asterisk asterisk  1869 Apr 20 16:04 sip_additional.conf

Its about ACL (SELINUX), but what does that . exactly represents.

Answer (score 5):

The `.` means that POSIX ACLs exist which may provide other access to the file.

Use the `getfacl` command to see them.

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting

http://linuxzoo.net/page/sec_file.html

```
-rxwrwxrwx.
  |   \  \ \___________
  |    \  \__          \
  |     |    \          \
owner  group  other    alternative access method indicator
```